# its possible to call java script array sort of data on by one after click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

im very confused , to explain my problem and I have searched in various posts in here, but I can't find the solution I'm facing .
so i want to ask, its possible to call an array sort of data in java script one by one after the button is clicked ?
explain I have a script random like this

```js
$(document).on("click", "#okok", function() {

  var myArray = [
    "5",
    "8",
    "7",
    "2"
  ];

  var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  var nilai = document.getElementById("pr");

  nilai.value = randomItem;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="pr" id="pr"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="okok" value="Start">
```

the script above displays array data one by one but random and not sort..
so i want the display data sort and not random
like 2 , 5 ,7 ,8

thanks

Comment: That output is sorted, not random. Which do you want: sorted or random because your question is very unclear.

Comment: i want sorted..

Comment: If you want things sorted why are you trying to make things random?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for

$(document).on("click","#okok",function(){

var myArray = [
   "5",
  "8",
  "7",
  "2"
 ];

var randomItem =[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]
var newArray = randomItem.concat(myArray)
var nilai = document.getElementById("pr");
nilai.value = newArray.sort()

});

Comment: Rando? Sort? What is that, If you need a sorted array and why are using random, just use `array.sort();`

Comment: i done tell this explain script random .. i want to call sort array like script random . one by one after click... if i make array.sort() so the result like this ['2','5','7','8'] , not one by one..

Comment: If you don't want random, then why is there `random` in your code??? Also, why would you first create an unsorted `["5","8","7","2"]` array only to then sort it? Then just define it as sorted. And then pick one by one from them at every click. This question is not clear.

Comment: You *have* to sort at some point, otherwise you won't know which one(s) you've viewed previous or where you are in the sort process.   Your current "random" doesn't get them one-by-one at all, it's picks a single random one each time.   If it was one-by-one then it would also remove them from the source list.   There's no equivalent of "get a random one infinite times" to "get them in order *infinite times*" - so you need to determine what it is you want.  At a guess, it's probably that you want 4 items back, sorted - so just sort up-front and keep a record of the index, or use yield.

Comment: Here's an example using yield, but it *does* sort (first, not when you click the button) and it seems you don't want a sort.   https://jsfiddle.net/bfxe74or/

Comment: okay thanks @freedomn-m u help me... nice this working

Comment: TBH, it's no different from pre-sorting and using an index.  Here's the same example using global variables (you could namespace or private them):  https://jsfiddle.net/t1h4jxg2/  You still need to sort first.